# Calculate Dynamic range of an Image?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

How to calculate Dynamic range of an Image using Opencv? What is the value of good dynamic range? How to calculate it using opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic range of an image is the log2 (as it is expressed in EVs) of the difference between the max and min lightness values; considering that the image is encoded with a linear response model.

With OpenCV you can access the pixel values of your image, so iterate and apply the formula.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please explain a bit more if possible? I am bit new. I was asked to calculate dynamic range of an image. And What will the good range?

Comment: Well, I'm no expert in OpenCV (I've read a few tutorials very briefly, but that's all), so I cannot help you with the implementation details.

About what's a good range, usually the greater the better.

Comment: Thanks once again. Can you please highlight the formula. log2 (as it is expressed in EVs). I couldnt understand this part alone. Sorry for troublin more.

Comment: Exposure Values are measured in "stops", doubling the amount of light in each unit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic range is 20*log(maxv / minv), where maxv and minv are the maximum and minimum pixel values of your image. This is not to be confused with information content, or Signal to Noise ratio, which measures the ratio of the signal (maximum-minimum values) divided by the noise floor.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\cxcore.h>

// Place your grayscale image with unsigned integer pixel values in img:
Mat img; 
double minVal; 
double maxVal; 
Point minLoc; 
Point maxLoc;

minMaxLoc( img, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc );

dr = 20*log10(maxVal/(1+minVal))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function wich returns a list of the calculated dynamic ranges of given images paths passed as an argument. I've calculated de dynamic range like:

- Get the RGB information of the pixels
- Calculate the brightness
- Get the max and min value of brightnes for the given photo
- apply the formula of dynamic range calculation

Here the code:

```
def dinamic_range(list_of_images):
    
    dinamic_range = []

    for img in list_of_images:
        image = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        pixel_brightness = []
        for x in range (1,480):
            for y in range (1,640):
                try:
                    pixel = image[x,y]
                    R, G, B = pixel
                    brightness = sum([R,G,B])/3
                    pixel_brightness.append(brightness)
                except IndexError:
                    pass
        din_range = round(np.log2(max(pixel_brightness))-np.log2(min((pixel_brightness))), 2)
        dinamic_range.append(din_range)
        print('The image', img, 'has a dinamic range of', din_range, 'EV')

    return dinamic_range
```